# How do I do a forward declaration of a struct with a typename?

Tags: c++, struct, typedef, typename

I am trying to do a forward declaration of a struct in c++ that has a typename. Something like this is entirely valid:

```
typedef struct foo foo;

struct foo{
    int f;
};
```

My struct just instead has a typename, so I tried this:

```
template <typename T>
typedef struct mV<T> mV;

template <typename T>
struct mV{
   //contents of struct
};
```

However, I then get the errors `a typedef cannot be a template`, `explicit specialization of undeclared template struct` and `redefinition of 'mV' as different kind of symbol`. How can I go about fixing that?

Comment: do you mean forward declaration?

Comment: You don't need those struct typedefs in C++, that's a C thing. Just do `struct foo;` (similarly with the template).

Comment: Not clear why you're defining an alias for something that matches its existing name. But here it is anyway: `template<typename T> using mV =  struct mV<T>;`

Comment: Something like `typedef struct foo foo;` is entirely valid but also entirely unnecessary (in parts); This is not C where you'd need to write `struct foo`, if you don't do the typedef; in C++ `struct foo;` is sufficient to allow for a use of `foo` as a type name without the use of an additional `struct` keyword...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're describing a *forward- declaration* . (A [`future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) is something completely different in modern C++).

`typedef` aliasing structure tags is not needed, and rarely desired, in C++. Instead you simply declare the class type and be done with it.

```
// typedef struct mV mV;  // not this
struct mV;                // instead this
```

The same goes for templates

```
template<class T>
struct mV;
```

If you need/want to attach an [alias to your template type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), you still can do so via `using`

```
template<class T>
struct mV;

template<class T>
using MyAliasNameHere = mV<T>;
```

Armed with all of that, and heading off what I surmise you'll be discovering in short order, you'll probably need to read this as well: [Why can templates only be implemented in header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file). Something tells me that's about to become highly relevant.